# DNS routing to private IP

Tags: azure, iis, networking, dns, ssl-certificate

We have 1 virtual machine with IIS in Azure, it doesn't hold the public IP address.
Its FQDN is machine.domain.local.

Its serving a service from IIS. We want to install certificate. However, we got the SSL by name **service.domain.com**.

If my machine would have public IP address I would have created A record for **service.domain.com** pointing to machines public IP address.

But we want this service to run internally, how we can we achieve this routing?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a CNAME record to map service.domain.com bind to machine.domain.local

Comment: but is possible to bind private IP address?, My machine doesn't have public IP address.

Comment: @akshayvithalkar   Where do you want to access the VM, is it in a local environment or Azure VNet?

Comment: We want to access this machine locally and through Azure Vnet. Setup is simple, We have machine connected to azure domain services with name machine.domain.local with private IP. Our organisation has internal ca which provides certificates with contoso.com not local. our dns is hosted in aws. in normal way we create A record which points to public Ip of vm. but we don't have public ip.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not Azure or DNS related, it looks like its IIS/certificate related.

You got certificate for service.domain.com, which you want to apply to website machine.domain.local.

You either get machine.domain.local added to **CName on Certificate** or change IIS website domain to service.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS to generate a self-signed certificate. Then, use an Azure Site-to-Site or Express Route to connect to On-premise. Set up a local host file entry on the servers for that domain & private IP address. This would work without a flaw but, it's tedious and not much of a recommended design.

What I would do is, I would MAP my domain to the private IP within the local DNS server and set the DNS as custom DNS on the VNET. This will make sure that all the VM's will point to the DNS server for any query and then start a recursive query.

> MAP to Private IP
>   Make record entry with the local DNS server with Private IP
>   Make changes at the Azure VNET to use the custom DNS, provide the DNS server private IP

Else
Do a host file entry manually on all the servers.

You can also read more along the lines of Private DNS on Azure:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-dns-private-zones-now-available-in-public-preview/

Regards,
Charan